# determine if a string has unique characters

Tags: algorithm

The  problem asks to "implement an algorithm to determine if a string has all unique character.

I saw the solution, but don't quite understand.

```
public boolean isUniqueChars(String str){

    if(str.length()>256) return false; 
        boolean[] char_set = new boolean[256];
        for(int i=0; i<str,length;i++){
        int val=str.charAt(i);
        if(char_set[val]) 
            return false;
        char_set[val]=true;
    } 
    return true;
}
```

Do we not use parseInt or (int) to convert the char to integer?

What does `boolean[] char set=new boolean[256]` means?
Why do we need this code:- `char_set[val]=true`?

Comment: It's not a very good algorithm, for one thing it assumes 8 bit chars.

Comment: Try writing your own, and ask here for specific problems.

Answer (score 1):

It is basically trying to initialize an array that keeps track of what characters have been seen in the string. So if an character has already appeared before, `char_set[val]` will be true, otherwise, it is false (default value).

**Do we use `parseInt` to convert characters to integers?** 
No, you do not have to. Characters can be thought as integers as internally, they are just some integers from the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/)

Comment: And what happens when the string contains "π" ?

Comment: Failed. It is a bad algorithm.